# Problems with HTML site showing up in mobile view

Tags: html, css

I know my site sucks, but that's not my issue right now. This is just a school assignment page. My problem is that when actually viewing my site in mobile view, the styling isn't responding correctly. There's suppose to be a hamburger menu in place of the nav bar when in mobile view. Can anyone take a look at my site and let me know what's going on?
https://aliciareneesnow.github.io/assignments/lesson-7/franklin-7.html

Answer (score 1):

Your media query is set to hide the hamburger at widths of 375 or greater and display the UL navigation at the same.

This width is very small and is likely smaller than your mobile display.

Try increasing your media query on both to something like:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px)
```

(Just as an example) to demonstrate it working properly in your mobile context.

Note: 768 is the collapse width on bootstrap, for reference.

Answer (score 0):

For styling, I typically use 4 media queries.

full width

```
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1000px), print and (min-width: 1000px) {
```

condensed

```
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 744px)
and (max-width : 999px) {
```

scalable

```
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 744px)
and (min-width : 481px) {
```

and mobile

```
@media 
only screen and (max-width : 480px),
only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
```

I set up my css files as full.css, condensed.css, scalable.css, and mobile.css and also have a style.css for default styling like colors and styles that go across all view sizes.

This has proven successful and has been easy to manage across all devices and screen sizes.  Once you have a good structure, you can show and hide things as needed on each query.

Once you adjust your widths, it should make your code show up better across devices.

Comment: Also be careful with 100% widths plus padding/margins.  The margins and paddings will cause your code to go beyond 100% and won't look correct.When I need margins/padding on 100% scaling, I use %'s for my margins and padding and subtract those from the 100%

Comment: That's so overkill, it can be simplified. you should look how frameworks like bootstrap and foundation implement their responsive grid. and btw `max-device-*` is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/device-width),

Your current code can be done like

`%%mobile code here%%` than:
//tablet query
`@media screen and (min-width: 768px)`
//laptop query
`@media screen and (min-width: 1024px)`
//large desktop query
`@media screen and (min-width: 1440px)`

This is using mobile first approach(change the values as you wish)